# Translating textbox input to spanish, chinese, deutsch

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization

I want to translate textbox value to specific language like spanish ,Chinse,Deutsch etc which all are having in below dropdown and i want to display textbox translated value in label but not gettin transalted value in label.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtmessage" runat="server" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="drop" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true"
        onselectedindexchanged="drop_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="en-US">English</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="ja-JP">Japanese</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="zh-CN">Chinse</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="de-DE">Deutsch</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="lblWelcome" meta:resourcekey="lblWelcome" 
           Text="Welcome" runat="server"  ></asp:Label>
```

code-behind:

```
        protected void drop_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(this.drop.SelectedValue);
             System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(this.drop.SelectedValue);

             lblWelcome.text=txtmessage.text;
        }
```

Comment: Are you asking for automatic translator functionality? There's no such thing in .NET framework, localization provides completely different functionality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google is an amazing tool to use when looking for something like this.
Google has Google Translate.

here is a code example you will need to alter it to work for what it is you are doing.

```
public static string Translate(string input, string languagePair, Encoding encoding)
{
string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);

string result = String.Empty;

using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
webClient.Encoding = encoding;
result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
}

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(result);
return doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//textarea[@name='utrans']").InnerText;
}

//Get the HtmlAgilityPack here: http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack
```

Comment: try adding this to the using: using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;